# Apex Trigger, change Account Owner to Event Owner

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm a newbie and I'd like to ask you a little help for what follows:

I create a new Event on an Account owned by User X and I assign this event to User Y.
Then, I'd like to have a trigger that changes the ownership of the Account to user Y (previously owned by User X).
How can I do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved just changing some fields on the account every time it a new event is created on this account.
You would need a trigger on Event:

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert){
    EventTriggerHandler.changeAccountOwner(Trigger.New);
}
```

then on the EventTriggerHandler class you would have this:

```
public static class EventTriggerHandler{
   public void changeAccountOwner(Event triggerNew){
      //we are cheching the prefix of the field on the event that tells you where it was created
      String idPrefix = String.valueOf(triggerNew.WhatId).subString(0,2);

      if(idPrefix == '001'){ // this is because the event may be created sometwhere else and not always in an account
          Account a = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id = :triggerNew.WhatId];

          //we just place the owner of the event to be the owner of the account
          a.OwnerId = triggerNew.OwnerId;
          update a;
      }
   }
}
```